# Get blog id of subdirectory multisite blog from name - *outside* of wordpress request processing

Tags: query

I have a Zend Framework 1.11.1 MVC application that has Wordpress 3.7.1 installed as a subdirectory multisite network below its "public" directory.  It uses must-use plugins to ensure that only logged-in users of the MVC application can access any of the blogs.  Basically, the earliest MU plugin runs the ZF application's bootstrap to get access to the ZF logged-in state, and hooks 'after-setup-theme' to a function that checks the MVC login state and permissions database and either just returns to allow access, or redirects to a page in the MVC application that explains why access to the blog was not allowed.  It's actually a bit more complicated (e.g. it creates a blog on the fly for a logged-in MVC user if one doesn't already exist), but that's the gist of it.

Within the plugins, I can call `get_blog_id_from_url` to get the blog id
from the request, and in principle it would return 0 if there is no such blog.  But if the request is for a blog that does not exist, then I get a 404 before any must use plugin runs.  I can work around that by issuing the requests to the root blog, and passing the site name information as a GET parameter.

But what I'd really like to do is have the MVC application code check for the existence of a particular blog, **without actually issuing a request to wordpress**.  I guess I could explicitly connect to the wordpress database and query the wp_blogs table, but I wanted to avoid getting that "intimate" with the wordpress code.  But figuring out the load dependencies needed in order to be able to call `get_blog_id_from_url` from MVC code was pretty tough.

I wound up trying something like this:

```
public function get_blog_id_for_mvc_request($blogname) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orig_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = PATH_CURRENT_SITE;
    // but PATH_CURRENT_SITE is not yet defined, so hardwire for now
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/wp/';
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/wp/wp-load.php');
    $site_id = get_blog_id_from_url(DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE, PATH_CURRENT_SITE . (strlen($blogname) ? "$blogname/" : ""));
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $orig_uri;
    return $site_id;
}
```

Modifying and restoring $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] made me feel pretty queasy, but looking at the wordpress code there appeared to be no other way.  This function actually did work in terms of getting the correct site id and continuing on to the MVC page that used the site id.  But after the page was rendered in the browser, httpd crashed (Apache 2.2.14 with PHP 5.3.1 on XP):
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions, either for tracking down/fixing the server crash, or for accessing the database directly in a simple and reliable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I get to answer my own question.

It turned out the problem wasn't in anything that wordpress was doing, but rather in the way I integrated it with the Zend application at a higher level than the code shown in the question.  That code in itself worked fine and did not cause Apache to crash.

The problem was that in the initial integration with the Zend MVC application, I only considered running wordpress queries that could access the MVC application's functions and database.  To do that, my first-run must-use plugin ran the bootstrap for the Zend application.  But then when I needed to access wordpress functionality from the Zend application, I didn't prevent the Zend bootstrap from running twice (once in setting up for the MVC request, and a second time in the initial must-use plugin for wordpress).

Preventing the Zend application bootstrap from running twice in the same request (using define/defined) fixed the apache crash, and now the posted code works fine.  Since I'm certain I'm not the only person integrating wordpress with a Zend Framework MVC application, I thought I should post this detailed answer.